# Probability of tiles in a game of Scrabble

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There are 100 tiles in a standard Scrabble set. The count and point values of the tiles are
shown in this table.

[image: Set]
￼￼

i. If I draw one tile from the bag of 100 tiles, what is the probability that it is a G?

ii. If I draw 3 tiles at once from the bag of 100 tiles, what is the probability that I have a J or an X or both?

iii. A full rack consists of 7 tiles. The minimum point value of 7 tiles is 5. If I draw 7 tiles at once from the bag of 100 tiles, what is the probability that my tiles add to 5 points?

iv. My opponent went first and drew 7 tiles at once from the bag of 100 tiles. To my surprise, she announced, “Darn, my tiles only add up to 5 points.” What is the probability that one of her tiles is an E?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine for a moment that you have the tiles marked as the "first G", the "second G", the "first E", the "second E", etc... so all tiles are distinct.  Note that you are now in an *equiprobable* sample space (meaning it is equally likely to draw one tile as it is another, and each batch of seven tiles is equally likely to occur as any other batch of seven tiles).

For an event $E$, denote $|E|$ to be the number of outcomes in the event $E$, and $|S|$ to be the total number of outcomes.

The probability of $E$ occurring is defined as $Pr(E):=\frac{|E|}{|S|}$  *note: this formula* **only** *works in an equiprobable sample space*

Part 1: How many ways can you draw a $G$ (of any kind) (not counting blanks).  Well, there are 3 G's and 100 tiles, so...

Part 2: If you draw three tiles, how many ways could you have gotten a J, an X, or both (not counting blanks).  This is the opposite of the probability of neither drawing a J nor an X.

$Pr(\text{at least one}~J~\text{or}~X~\text{in 3 draws}) = 1-Pr(\text{no}~J~\text{and no}~X~\text{in 3 draws})$

How many ways can you choose 3 tiles if none of them are a J or an X?  (there are 98 of them still available to **choose** from and you want three)  (The sample space in this case is all ways of **choosing** 3 tiles from the 100)

Part 3:  If the points add to 5, the only way this can happen is if two of them are the two blank tiles (since all other tiles are worth at least 1 point each).  What are the other five tiles?  (they all must have been worth 1 point, how many of those are there?)  (Our sample space here is going to be all ways of drawing 7 tiles from the 100)

Part 4:  You already know that your opponent's points add to 5, so you may restrict your attention to a much smaller sample space: the possibilities found in part 3.  How many of those in part 3 have one$\!\!~^*$ E?  (It is unclear whether you mean exactly one, or at least one).

The official definition to use here (instead of "relabeling" what the sample space is) is that the probability of an event $E$ occuring given that we already know that the event $F$ occurs is:  Probability of $E$ *given* $F$ = $Pr(E|F) = \frac{Pr(E\cap F)}{Pr(F)}$ which for equiprobable sample spaces simplifies further to $=\frac{|E\cap F|}{|F|}$

Comment: for part 4, at least one E

Comment: In either case, apply inclusion-exclusion for part 4.  The opposite of "at least one E" is "zero E's".

Comment: Im still having trouble finding the answer here, I understand the concept, but don't know where to start on part 3

Comment: For part three, there are 68 tiles which are worth one point, and there are 2 tiles worth zero points (all other tiles are worth 2 or more points).  Since the total number of points is five, that necessarily means that you use the two blank tiles and five of the 68 one-point tiles.  Setting it up as a multiplication principle question, pick which two of the two zero-point tiles you use and then pick which five of the one-point tiles you use, for a total of $\binom{2}{2}\cdot\binom{68}{5}$ number of different ways of getting a 5-point rack(again with the simplification that all tiles different)

Comment: Our counting-formulae work best when working in an equiprobable space.  You could approach it more directly, treating all $E$'s as being indistinguishable, however the easiest to explain method that way would be with a tree diagram, and there would be well over 8 million leaves on the tree, making it infeasible to work with.

Comment: so the probability of at least one E then for problem 4 would be 12 in 68?

Comment: That would be the probability that if you draw one tile out of all of the tiles with point-value 1, that it is an $E$.  Your opponent might have five E's, or two E's, etc...  Think about the inclusion-exclusion principle as I suggested earlier and look at the probability of your opponent having a 5-point rack with zero E's.  (You know two of the tiles are blanks.  Out of the 56 non-E one-point tiles, choose five of them)

Comment: so the probability of at least one E would then be  1- C(56, 5) and then i would divide that by the answer from part 3 to get the answer to part 4

Comment: You have the right idea, however do not confuse the phrase "number of ways" with the term "probability".  Or rather you forgot to divide the previous thought by the sample space size.  1-C (56,5)/C (68,5) will be the final answer to part four.  Note that the 1 is *not* being divided and stands separate.

Comment: oh ok because the total probability of not choosing a E would be C (56,5)/C (68,5) so you then subtract that from one.

Just to clarify problem 3, the final answer would come out to (C(2,2)*C(68,5))/C(100,7)

Comment: Indeed.  That is correct.