# Probability of picking exactly 5 'E' Scrabble tiles when drawing 7 from a standard bag of 100?

Tags: probability

Given a bag of 100 Scrabble tiles, 12 of which are E tiles, what is the probability of drawing 7 tiles where exactly 5 of them are Es and 2 of them are not Es?

Based on [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192710/probability-of-tiles-in-a-game-of-scrabble) [three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496883/probability-of-pulling-a-word-out-of-a-bag-of-scrabble-tiles) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207483/what-is-the-probability-that-you-will-draw-7-vowel-tiles-from-a-scrabble-bag-wit), I took a stab at the answer:

There are 12 Es to start, so for the event of drawing 5 Es, the number of outcomes for that would be: $12 \times 11 \times 10 \times 9 \times 8$

For the other 2 tiles, there are 88 non-E tiles to start, so the number of outcomes would be: $88 \times 87$

Together, the numerator becomes: $12 \times 11 \times 10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 88 \times 87$

For the denominator, the total number of outcomes is based on how many tiles there are for each draw. So: $100 \times 99 \times 98 \times 97 \times 96 \times 95 \times 94$

Which gives us this fraction:

$$\frac{12 \times 11 \times 10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 88 \times 87}{100 \times 99 \times 98 \times 97 \times 96 \times 95 \times 94} = \frac{727,626,240}{80,678,106,432,000} = 0.000009018880985 = 0.0009018880985\%$$

As *X* out of *Y*:

- $\approx$ 9 out of 1,000,000 OR
- $\approx$ 1 out of 110,879

Is that right?  And whether it is or not, how could I better articulate the answer, because I don't really know what I'm doing in this space, and it strikes me as sloppy and bad.

Comment: Do you mean draw *exactly* $5$ E's (and two non-E's) or is it draw *at least* $5$ E's?

Comment: @coffeemath Ah, good question. I mean *exactly* 5 E's. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: You're on the right track, but you've made a mistake. You're using permutations... and you've only counted the permutations where the first 5 letters are E and the last two are not. There are also other permutations where 5 E's are selected, but they aren't the first five. This approach is difficult. It is better to use combinations instead. Everything you'll do is almost the same. But instead of P(12,5), you use C(12,5) etc.

Comment: @AmeetSharma Can you give an example of what the answer would look like using combinations instead of permutations? Since it's multiplication, I don't think there's a distinction between "first 5" vs "last two". Even if it was written out as 88 x 87 x 12 x 11 x 10 x 9 x 8, it would still be the same answer. Can you help me understand what you mean?

Comment: @machaira9, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to choose 5 E tiles out of 12.

The number of ways of doing this is $\binom{12}{5}$.

You need to choose 2 non E tiles out of 88.

The number of ways of doing this is $\binom{88}{2}$.

So the number of ways to get the 7 tiles you need = $\binom{12}{5}  $ $\binom{88}{2}$

So the probability = $\frac{\binom{12}{5}\binom{88}{2}}{\binom{100}{7}} = \frac{2871}{15,158,675}$ which is approx $0.000189$

EDIT:

If you take the answer you posted and multiply by $\binom{7}{5}$ you get the answer above. Reason being... to get all the permutations, you need to first make a choice of which 5 positions out of the 7 get E's. For each of those choices, you get $12 \times 11 \times 10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 88 \times 87$ permutations.

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me understand your notation? (The numbers in parentheses.)

Comment: The parentheses numbers are binomial coefficients: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: By "which 5 positions out of the 7 get E's," do you mean calculating the probability if the Es are in positions 1-5, 1-4 and 6, 1-4 and 7, etc?

Comment: Yes. If you use permutations, then the probability the E's are in just positions 1-5 is 0.000009018880985. But then you have to multiply by $\binom{7}{5}$ which is the total number of choices of 5 spots out of 7.

Comment: Ah, excellent! That was my initial intuition, but I had no idea how to articulate it properly, and then I ended up down the path you set in my question above. Thank you so much for your help!